# Limited multi-core speedup with GEOS reentrant API

Tags: multithreading, geospatial, geos

When calling GEOS functions on GEOSGeometry objects in multiple threads I'm seeing only about a 2x speedup over sequential execution.

For my test computation I create a `GEOSContextHandle_t`, and then create many `GEOSGeometry` objects.  Then in many threads I call a reentrant function like  `GEOSBufferWithStyle_r` in a for loop on all of the polygons.

This is only about 2x faster on a four core machine (i5) over sequential operation.  Is there anything I should be doing to improve parallelism?

I am doing this within Cython, properly wrapping code in `nogil` blocks.